# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n-100}{n^2+n+4}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So far I have set up the initial step using the definition, $$\left|\frac{n-100}{n^2+n+4}-0\right|<\epsilon$$ for $n>N$. I then split up the absolute value by $$\frac{\left|n-100\right|}{\left|n^2+n+4\right|}.$$ Using triangle inequality I got $$\frac{\left|n-100\right|}{\left|n^2+n+4\right|}\leq \frac{n+100}{n^2+n+4}$$ (since $n$ is always positive). Clearly  $$\frac{n+100}{n^2+n+4}<\frac{n}{n^2+n+4}$$ because the numerator is smaller. This is where I get stuck, Since I have a lone $n$ in the numerator, I know I have to manipulate the denominator, in particular to find a way to make it larger to continue the chain of inequalities, but I can't think of how to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** It gets a lot easier if you start by noting that when $n>100$ we have $n^2+n+4>n^2$ and $0<n-100<n$, and therefore $$ \frac{n-100}{n^2+n+4} < \frac{n-100}{n^2} < \frac{n}{n^2}$$

Comment: Do you mean when $n>100$?

Comment: x @Jeff: Yes, fixed.

Comment: Or just divide top and bottom by $n$ then as its continuous you can break it in parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Henning Makholm did a good comment and to elaborate it more (formally),we do the following.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N>100$ and $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Thus, if $n> N$ then 
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{n-100}{n^2+n+4}-0\right|&=\frac{n-100}{n^2+n+4}\\
&<\frac{n}{n^2+n+4}\\
&<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}< \frac{1}{N}<\epsilon.
\end{align}$$
Done. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you got inspired by Henning Makholm's hint in the comments (not saying that you did), I think it would be correct to give him some credit

Comment: I did not noticed it as I am typing at that time. See the time difference. Anyway, thanks for the reminder @FraGrechi

Answer (score 0):

Divide top and bottom by $n$ to get $$\frac{1-\frac{100}{n}}{n+1+\frac{4}{n}}$$ You can show that anything in the form $\frac{c}{n}$ has limit 0. Can you figure out the rest from here?

Comment: Why divide by not $n^2$?

Comment: You could do that also.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show $|\frac {n-100}{n^2 + n + 4} |< \epsilon$ which if $n > 100$ is the same as showing

$\frac {n-100}{n^2 + n + 4} < \epsilon$ which if $n^2 + n + 4 > 100^2 + 100 + 4 >0$ is the same as showing

$n  < \epsilon n^2 + \epsilon n + 4\epsilon+100$

or $1 < \epsilon n + \epsilon +4\epsilon/n + 100/n$ which if $n > \frac 1 {\epsilon}$

$1 = \frac 1{\epsilon}\epsilon < \epsilon n <  \epsilon n + \epsilon +4\epsilon/n + 100/n$

is true and the is nothing more to show.

We simply have to assume $n > \max (100,\frac 1 {\epsilon})$.